# setting control source property of a textbox of subform in its parent form in ms access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a textbox on a subform the controlsource property of which is to be changed on click of a label on the parent form of the same. I have tried the following ways none of which worked at all,

```
Form_frmWOMAINMENU.[frmWOMAINSUBMENU].Form.[txtDate].Control.ControlSource _
                                                   = "Raised"

Forms("frmWOMAINMENU").[frmWOMAINSUBMENU].Form.[txtDate].ControlSource _
                                                   = "Raised"  

Me.[frmWOMAINSUBMENU].Form.[txtDate].ControlSource = "Raised"
```

Can anyone suggest me how it works?

`frmWOMAINMENU` is the parent form and `frmWOMAINSUBMENU` is the subform.
Also, "Raised" comes from a sql query written as string in the vba code.
I tried the same in the subform like this:
    `me.txtDate.ControlSource="Raised"` 
and it worked fine.However,I cannot change control source of the textbox thrice in the subform.

Answer (score 2):

It will be more like:

```
Forms!frmWOMAINMENU!frmWOMAINSUBMENU!txtDate.ControlSource = "Raised"
```

As long as on your parent form, the actual sub-form item is named "frmWOMAINSUBMENU" rather than "Subform1" or whatever the default naming is. Or in other words, the parent form is referred to by name and then the sub-form is referred to as whatever it's called on the parent form.  Hope that makes sense : )

Comment: Just used this and worked wonders    Me.frmWOMAINSUBMEN!txtDate.ControlSource = "Raised"
I think the problem was the word "Form" in my code.And since the code is in the form "frmWOMAINMENU", "Forms!frmWOMAINMENU" gave an error.I hope I understood right. :) Thanks!

Comment: @user1175126 Ah good point, what I wrote is more for referring to any open form, glad you got a solution though : )